# How to use imagemagick "convert" to create Google Earth pyramid files

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have a large image that I am using imagemagick to convert into tiles for use in a Google Earth KML as explained here
[instructions on image pyramid construction](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/photos#gigapixelPhotos)
The idea is to chop up the images into 4 pieces, then 16, then 64, etc.

To keep things simple, I made the image canvas 4096x4096 so that dividing it in will produce equal size files. The basic command is very simple. For example:

> convert large.png -crop 512x512 tiles.png

The issue is the convert command creates file names sequentially, while google needs a format of row column. For instance if there were four files output, the file names should be:

```
tiles00.png
tiles01.png
tiles10.png
tiles11.png
```

I brute forced renaming scripts for up to 64 files, but before doing the 256 file case, I'd like to know if there is a simpler way to generate the file names. I'm using linux.

Comment: What version of Imagemagick?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way in Imagemagick 6 using for loops.

lena.png

[image]

The lena.png image is 256x256. I choose 128x128 size tiles. So there will be a total of 2 rows and 2 columns for four output images.

```
infile="lena.png"
tx=128
ty=128
ncols=`convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:floor(w/$tx)]" info:`
nrows=`convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:floor(h/$ty)]" info:`
for ((j=0; j<nrows; j++)); do
offy=$((j*ty))
for ((i=0; i<ncols; i++)); do
offx=$((i*tx))
convert lena.png -crop ${tx}x${ty}+${offx}+${offy} +repage lena_tile${j}${i}.png
done
done
```

lena_tile00

[image]

lena_tile01

[image]

lena_tile10

[image]

lena_tile11

[image]

An alternate, more compact way is to use -set filename command with fx calculations to name the files in the image chain.

```
infile="lena.png"
tx=128
ty=128
ncols=`convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:floor(w/$tx)]" info:`
nrows=`convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:floor(h/$ty)]" info:`
convert "$infile" -crop ${tx}x${ty} -set filename:row_col "%[fx:floor(t/$nrows)]%[fx:mod(t,$ncols)]" "lena_tile%[filename:row_col].png"
```

See:
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#set
https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php

Comment: I used the first solution. The file naming needs the leading zeros. I tried using %01d in front of the row and column, but that didn't work. BTW I studied signal processing and am quite familiar with Lena.

Comment: You did not mention anything about leading zeros and your example does not show that. So I am not sure how you want the output formatted. But you can add `jj=$(printf "%01d" $j)` and then change ${j} to ${jj}. But you would likely need to add a separator between the rows and columns in your output such as `lena_tile_${jj}_${ii}.png`

Comment: I sort mentioned the leading zero, perhaps implicit in tiles01.png versus tiles1.png. However I managed to solve a library issue and got vips installed. I'm going to try the dzsave. All this said, it seems a shame that imagemagick can't do this naming in a more native manner. I'm going to get an account on their forum and making a suggestion.

Comment: `@gariac` That is a good suggestion for an enhancement. Also perhaps one of the other users on the Imagemagick forum can suggest a way that I did not consider or know. IM 7 has much more flexibility (as seen in my second method) than IM 6. So perhaps there is a way already. Sorry, but I interpreted your tile01 to mean row 0 and column 1 rather than leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make your own in order to learn about the process? If not, existing tools like [dzsave](http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-dzsave) can build complete pyramids for you very quickly in a single command. For example:

```
$ vipsheader wtc.jpg 
wtc.jpg: 10000x10000 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, jpegload
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vips dzsave wtc.jpg x --layout google
211224:1.52
$ ls -R x | wc
   2404    2316   15186
```

So that's making a google-style pyramid of 2400 tiles in directory `x` from a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel JPG image. It takes about 1.5s and 210mb of ram.

There's a chapter in the manual introducing `dzsave`:

http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html